# How do I insert header with picture and filename when new workbook is being generated?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to insert header with picture and some texts by copying values from 2 different cells. I tried googling but somehow what I manage to get is the image only appears when in the printable mode but not in the workbook. Below is the code that I've tried.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Output")

With ws.PageSetup
   .CenterFooterPicture = "&G" 'Specifies that you want an image in your footer
   .CenterFooterPicture.Filename = "C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Desert.jpg"

End With
```

While a new workbook is being generated, the header with picture and the texts should be inside as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`CenterFooterPicture`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.pagesetup.centerfooterpicture) documentation notes:

> It is required that "&G" is a part of the **`CenterFooter`** property string in order for the image to show up in the center footer.

Similar to the example the documentation provides, try:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Output")

With ws.PageSetup
   .CenterFooterPicture.Filename = "C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Desert.jpg"
End With

ws.PageSetup.CenterFooter = "&G" 'Specifies that you want an image in your footer
```

**EDIT:**

Based on the comment that you want the image in the left header, try this similar snippet:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Output")

With ws.PageSetup
   .LeftHeaderPicture.Filename = "C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Desert.jpg"
End With

ws.PageSetup.LeftHeader = "&G"
```

Comment: But the position of the image that I want is not in the centre is located at top left comer of the workbook

Comment: I did the workbook is named Output and the worksheet is Sheet1. I've change it to Sheet1 still giving me the same error

Comment: Set header = Workbooks("Output.xls").Worksheets("Sheet1")  It doesnt work too

Comment: What is `header`??

Comment: I replace ws to header as a variable

Comment: This seems like a new question, unrelated to the `CenterFooter` issue. Maybe edit your question with all of the code you are trying and the specific error message.

Comment: I didn't realize you wanted a left header instead of a center footer. See the edit :)

Comment: Same problem the image only comes up when in the printable page. I need it to be in the sheet when the workbook is being generated.

Comment: A header/footer is visible if you change the view to Page Layout - but otherwise I think you just need to insert the picture directly and avoid using a header or footer.

Comment: hmm I got it but how do I change the size of it and place in on the top lefthand side of the workbook? And by any chance do you know how to I copy data 2 cells from an input workbook and paste onto the header?